# Update SQL column Type Text with a DateTime type from Dataframe column

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a dataframe.  One of the columns is a timestamp type.  My SQL column is TEXT type.  I need to update the records in the SQL Table with the column from the dataframe.

Based upon the tutorial on pysqlite, I need to convert it to a list, then make a tuple with the index to be able to update SQL table.  But it gets rejected because it says "InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type."  I appreciate the help!

```
cursor = con.cursor()
DynamicTPIndex = DynamTPs.index.values.tolist()
DynTP = DynamTPs['Dynamic_TP_1_lane_Time'].tolist()
cursor = con.cursor()
sql_update_queryTP = '''UPDATE GBPAUD_TA SET Dynamic_TP_1_lane_Time = ? WHERE Ticket = ?''' 
dataTP = zip(DynTP, DynamicTPIndex)
cursor.executemany(sql_update_queryTP, dataTP)
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Few additional things:  my datetime format is in ISO8601 format.
Sample Data:

```
Ticket  Dynamic_TP_1_lane_Time     Dynamic_TP_1_lane_Price
356137189   2020-06-01 06:17:00    1.8423
356178592   2020-06-01 08:30:00    1.8392
356188961   2020-06-01 09:13:00    1.836
356666230   2020-06-02 17:00:00    1.8281
356782143   2020-06-02 17:58:00    1.8219
356810290   2020-06-02 20:09:00    1.8217
356893467   2020-06-03 03:16:00    1.8167
```

I have tried replacing zip with a merge function from here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-merge-two-lists-into-list-of-tuples/.  Same error about binding

Comment: You are trying to assign the `Dynamic_TP_1_lane_Time` column to a list, which doesn't make much sense (it needs to be a scalar value).  Please explain your perceived logic here.

Comment: Not my logic.  Just trying to do something and then followed the pieced together guidance I have found.  This piece came from https://pynative.com/python-sqlite-update-table/, in the Section "Python update multiple rows of SQLite table using cursor’s executemany()".  There he says with executemany(), you are passing a list...?

Comment: OK, I get it.  Maybe include the data you are binding along with the type, as this seems to be the cause of the error.

Comment: From the data supplied above, the index ("Ticket" ) is the first list assigned to the variable DynamicTPIndex, and the first column ("Dynamic_TP_1_lane_Time") is the second list assigned to DynTP.  Do you need these posted above seperately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much troubleshooting, I finally figured out that the dtype was pandas timestamp.  SQL cannot accept this dtype.  It requires python datetime dtype to import into SQL.  Therefore, for the datetime column I required to:

```
Date_object = DynamTPs['Dynamic_TP_1_lane_Time'].dt.to_pydatetime()
```